# Android Webview share with whatsapp,twitter,facebook y google+

Tags: android-intent, webview, webview-android, whatsapp, uiwebview

Necesito uno o varios enlaces, que me permitan compartir un texto con enlace de mi aplicación dentro de  mi aplicación Android Webview,
Lo he intentado con 
Intent View,set package,start activity,[share with] whatsapp,twitter,facebook,google+.

Al compartir en whatsapp quiero que me deje seleccionar el contacto,lo único que consigo es el Activity en blanco, me pregunto si podría con el intent iniciar whatsapp fuera de mi Activity de manera que en el launcher de android me aparezca whatsapp, y asi con demas aplicaciones mencionadas anteriormente, quiero que la gente pueda informar a otra sobre mi aplicacion y quiero un botón que abra mi perfil de fecebook,google + twitter etc en las aplicaciones instaladas en mi dispositivo,
google +twitter facebook,instagram etc... 
Adjunto el codigo:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView WebView, String url) {

if url start with whatsapp, facebook,twitter,google+
if url contains   whatsapp, facebook,twitter,google+


Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
whatsappIntent.setType("text/plain");
whatsappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Enlace de mi Aplicacion con un texto e imagen");
try {
    activity.startActivity(whatsappIntent);
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    ToastHelper.MakeShortText("Whatsapp no esta instalado.");
}
public void invokeShare(Activity activity, String quote, String credit) {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, activity.getString(R.string.share_subject));
    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Enlace de mi Aplicacion con un texto e imagen");    
    activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, activity.getString(R.string.share_title)));
}

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView WebView, String url) {

if(url.startsWith("whatsapp://")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Enlace de mi Aplicacion con un texto e imagen");
            intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            startActivity(intent);
            intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");


Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Enlace de mi Aplicacion con un texto e imagen");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
try {
    Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    waIntent.setType("text/plain");
    PackageInfo info=pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Enlace de mi Aplicacion con un texto e imagen");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, "Compartir con:"));
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "WhatsApp no esta instalado!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
} }
            return true;
        }else{ return false; }



Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
                intent.setClassName("com.facebook.katana", "com.facebook.katana");
                startActivity(intent);


                Intent iintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                iintent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("Enlace de mi Aplicacion con un texto e imagen"));
                iintent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                startActivity(iintent);


                myBrowser.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Chrome");


                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("text/plain");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Enlace de mi Aplicacion con un texto e imagen");
                //intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                startActivity(intent);
                intent.setPackage("com.Whatsapp");

                PackageManager packageManager = MainActivity.this.getPackageManager();
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

                try {
                    url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + 111111111 + "&text=" + URLEncoder.encode("Enlace de mi Aplicacion con un texto e imagen", "UTF-8");
                    i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    if (i.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
                        MainActivity.this.startActivity(i);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();


                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                sendIntent.putExtra("jid",111111111);
                sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                startActivity(sendIntent);


                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("text/plain");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Enlace de mi Aplicacion con un texto e imagen");
                //intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                startActivity(intent);
                intent.setPackage("com.Whatsapp");


                Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.whatsapp");
                if (launchIntent != null) {
                    startActivity(launchIntent);//null pointer check in case package name was not found
                }


                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Enlace de mi Aplicacion con un texto e imagen");
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                startActivity(sendIntent);
                // sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                startActivity(sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp"));
                */
                /*
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Enlace de mi Aplicacion con un texto e imagen");
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                // Put this line here
                sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                //
                startActivity(sendIntent);*/

                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Enlace de mi Aplicacion con un texto e imagen");
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                startActivity(sendIntent);


                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Enlace de mi Aplicacion con un texto e imagen");
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                startActivity(sendIntent);
                sendIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.whatsapp");


                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("whatsapp://send?text="));
                if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivity(intent);
                }


                //  Uri IntentUri = Uri.parse(url);
                Uri IntentUri = Uri.parse("whatsap://send?text=");
                Intent whatssap1Intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, IntentUri);
                whatsapp1ntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.whatsapp");


                PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
                try {

                    Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    waIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    String text = "YOUR TEXT HERE";

                    PackageInfo info =pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
                    //Check if package exists or not. If not then code
                    //in catch block will be called
                    waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

                    waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, "Share with"));

                } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }

                 PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
                    try {
                        Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        waIntent.setType("text/plain");
                        String text = "This is  a Test"; // Replace with your own message.

                        PackageInfo info=pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
                        //Check if package exists or not. If not then code
                        //in catch block will be called
                        waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

                        waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, "Share with"));

                    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }catch(Exception e){

                    }




            }


                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Enlace de mi Aplicacion con un texto e imagen");
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                startActivity(sendIntent);
                sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

                PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
                try {
                    Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    waIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    PackageInfo info=pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
                    waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                    waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Enlace de mi Aplicacion con un texto e imagen");
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, "Compartir con:"));
                } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "WhatsApp no esta instalado!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }



if(url.contains("whatsapp://send?"))
                {


                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("whatsapp://send?text="Enlace de mi Aplicacion con un texto e imagen));
                    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                    //  Uri IntentUri = Uri.parse(url);
                    Uri IntentUri = Uri.parse("whatsapp://send?text="Enlace de mi Aplicacion con un texto e imagen"");
                    Intent WPIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, IntentUri);
                    WPIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                    //Intent WPintent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.whatsapp");

                    if (WPIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        startActivity(WPIntent);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Si de algo te sirve, yo uso lo siguiente: Addthis.com

en mi android app.

```
public static boolean checkUrl(Activity mActivity, String url) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
        phoneLink(mActivity, url);
        return true;
    } else if (url.startsWith("sms:")) {
        smsLink(mActivity, url);
        return true;
    } else if (url.startsWith("mailto:")) {
        email(mActivity, url);
        return true;
    } else if (url.startsWith("geo:") || uri.getHost().equals("maps.google.com")) {
        url = url.replace("https://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=", "geo:");
        map(mActivity, url);
        return true;
    } else if (url.contains("youtube")) {
        openYoutube(mActivity, url);
        return true;
    } else if (uri.getHost().equals("play.google.com")) {
        openGooglePlay(mActivity, url);
        return true;
    } else if (url.contains("whatsapp")) {
        send(mActivity, url);
        return true;
    } else if (url.contains("facebook")) {
        sendfacebook(mActivity, url);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

private static void send(Activity mActivity, String url) {
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    String msg = uri.getQueryParameter("url");
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "promoción en Pmotion: " +msg );
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    mActivity.startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Espero te sirva